# How to bind a list item to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I am retrieving a bunch of strings after doing comma separation. Next i want to bind it to a gridview. But, it throws an error:

> A field or property with the name _barcodes was not found on the selected data source.

Below is the code:

```
private void RetrieveScannedBarcodes()
////code to retrieve the barcodes
    foreach (var item in ScannedBarcodes)
    {
        _barcodes.AddRange(item.Split(','));
        foreach (var b in _barcodes)
        {
            gvScannedBarcodes.DataSource = b;
            gvScannedBarcodes.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And the gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvScannedBarcodes" runat="server" AllowSorting="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="25"
    Width="741px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="_barcodes" HeaderText="Barcodes" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="50" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A field or property with the name _barcodes was not found on the
>   selected data source.

You are binding the string as a datasource to GridView instead of collection like `DataTable` of `List` that has column or property named `_barcodes`.

You have a list `ScannedBarcodes` that contains comma separated bar codes strings and you probably want all the barcodes from that list to be binded with GridView. Now you have to get all the bar codes from `ScannedBarcodes` in to some collection have `_barcodes` as column.

You can use Linq query to get all the bar codes using `SelectMany` and `Select` and put the result into anonymous object list having column name `_barcodes` like this.

```
gvScannedBarcodes.DataSource =  ScannedBarcodes.SelectMany(s=>s.Split(',')
                                .Select(b=>new {_barcodes = b}));
gvScannedBarcodes.DataBind();
```

To make it simple to understand see the following example.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(new string []{"1,2,3","4,5,6"});
gvScannedBarcodes.DataSource = list.SelectMany(l=>l.Split(',')
                               .Select(b=>new {_barcodes = b}));
gvScannedBarcodes.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a `List` to a GridView directly.

```
gvScannedBarcodes.DataSource = ScannedBarcodes;
gvScannedBarcodes.DataBind();
```

And the `DataField` must match the properties in the Class.

```
class Barcode
{
    public string myBarcode { get; set; }
}

<asp:BoundField DataField="myBarcode"
```